# Merge these 2 SQL queries into one with same result

Tags: mysql

I need some assistance in merging these 2 sql queries into one and get the same result.

### Database structure:

`Table: sqldb1_meta`

`Columns: ipaddress, data`

### First query:

`SELECT * FROM sqldb1_meta WHERE ipaddress LIKE '%10.10.1.2%'`

From the first query i get all that matches coulmn ipaddress 10.10.1.2, the other column has data for this entry, in this case it was '92"

### Second Query:

`SELECT * FROM sqldb1_meta WHERE data LIKE '92'`

Now i get all the data i want displayed, everything that had value 92 from column data. I can only know it was 92 based on the first query.

**How do i combine this into one query instead of having to run 2?**

Comment: Maybe you need `self join`. But, please provide sample table data with expected output; currently the problem statement is unclear.

Comment: Ever heard of AND?

Comment: But how can i use AND when i do not know which result column data is going to have until i run the first query? The only reason i know it's 92 is because i ran the first query, how do i use the result of the first query to run a second query without having 2 statements like this? The expected result is just simply viewing whatever matches the second query, in this case whatever content in the database column data that has "92"

Comment: data is a terrible name for a column.

Answer (score 0):

Need more details, but maybe `inner join` the table to it self (self join) or `union`...

Answer (score 0):

Use your first `Select` query as a [Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html) in the `Where` condition.

```
SELECT `ipaddress`, 
       `data` 
FROM sqldb1_meta 
WHERE `data` IN (
                 SELECT `data` 
                 FROM sqldb1_meta 
                 WHERE `ipaddress` LIKE '%10.10.1.2%'
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post, you just need to combine both conditions on the where clause using the and operator

```
SELECT * FROM sqldb1_meta WHERE ipaddress LIKE '%10.10.1.2%' and data LIKE '92'
```